# divide row into two equal columns using two spans

Tags: html, css

Following is  my simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<span style="display:inline-block;width:49%;text-align:center"> some text</span>
                 <span style="display:inline-block;width:49%;text-align:center"> some text</span>

</body>
</html>
```

I want row to be divided into 2 equal space/columns but when I use 50% width, second span comes to the next row.

**What I did?**

fixed both widths to 49% then it is working but I want space to be equally divided using 50%.

What am I missing?

Comment: cool... nice to know about this issue..

Answer (score 1):

**Using Flex**

```css
.wrap{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.block-a{
  width:50%;
  background:green;
  
}

.block-b{
  width:50%;
  background:gold;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

<span class="block-a"> some text</span>
<span class="block-b"> some text</span>

</div>
```

**Using Flot**

```css
.block-a{
  width:50%;
  background:green;
  float:left;
  
}

.block-b{
  width:50%;
  background:gold;
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

<span class="block-a"> some text</span>
<span class="block-b"> some text</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add `float:left`

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnm04fby/)

Comment: Great.. Do you explain with some reasoning?